# Sending mail when mail server is not on web host

Tags: php, email

I am hosting a client's site while they are running an exchange server at their location to handle the email.  Whenever I try to send email via PHP to one of their email addresses it fails as it is looking for the address on the local system.

Can I force the mail function to look outside of the server for sending mail?

I'm on a Media Temple dedicated virtual box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the easier way would be to not use the `mail` function, but a library that deals with sending mail by SMTP -- the SMTP being on your client's server.

You can for instance take a look at [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) (which has a pretty good reputation, and is used by the Symfony Framework), or [`PEAR::Mail`](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail).

Answer (score 0):

Media Temple has probably set it up this way to reduce the spam problems.  You will have to ask Media Temple about the configuration.

I've worked with Media Temple before.  They are pretty responsive to their customers needs.  Chances are they have been asked and answered this question before.